# withLatestFrom in effect wrong type

Tags: angular, rxjs, ngrx, ngrx-effects

I have the following selector :

```
export const selectMissionState: MemoizedSelector<object, State> = createFeatureSelector<State>('missions');

export const selectAll: (state: object) => Array<IMission> = featureAdapter.getSelectors(selectMissionState).selectAll;
```

In my effect I do the following =>

```
  @Effect()
  applyMissionReroute$ = this.actions$.pipe(
    ofType<featureActions.ApplyMissionReroute>(featureActions.ActionTypes.ApplyMissionReroute),
    withLatestFrom(MissionsStoreSelectors.selectAll()),
    switchMap(([action, state]) => {})
  );
```

But I face a problem, Although my selectAll is supposed to return an Array (which is what the compiler say when I over, my [action, state] is just a IMission.

What My state is a just a var IMission and not a Array ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should call `withLatestFrom` either with `this.store` to receive entire store state, or with `this.store.pipe(select(...selector...))` for only a slice of state.

With this change below, you'll receive result of selector inside `selectAll` argument.

```
@Effect()
applyMissionReroute$ = this.actions$.pipe(
  ofType<featureActions.ApplyMissionReroute
    (featureActions.ActionTypes.ApplyMissionReroute),
  withLatestFrom(this.store.pipe(select(MissionsStoreSelectors.selectAll))),
  switchMap(([action, selectAll]) => {
    ..
  })
);
```

Hope it will help you.